# Azure Pipeline with persistent build directory

Tags: azure, devops, yocto

In Azure Pipelines, we are checking out two repositories, which are stored in agent/_work/[AgentID]/s. We are building a Linux Image via Yocto and the build takes about 6hrs initially. The next build only builds the incremental changes and so it takes only 3 minutes. But using azure Pipelines, the build folder is never the same since the buildId changes and so the build always takes about 6hrs. Is there a way to have always the same build directory? I failed until now because the build directory always has to be under the agent directory (which changes)

from agent/[id]/s i can only go down. when i tried to use a higher Directory (which would be the same for every build), i am not allowed to do so.